# How to extract coordinates from addOnSuccessListener in FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: java, location, fusedlocationproviderclient

I need to extract coordinates from `addOnSuccessListener` method. Help me please with that

```
      fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->

      // I need to return value
   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the location parameter in arguments, for extracting latitude and longitude just call

```
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
        if (location != null) {
            var latitude : double = location.latitude
            var longitude : double = location.longitude
    }
  }
```

Make sure to surround this with location null check as it can return null in case GPS is switched off.